# Rails authenticate mongodb_logger with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've got installed gems `mongodb_logger` and `devise`.
I was wondering how to restrict access to users who are registered in `devise` ?
I tried as follows( restricting to users with `admin` role)

> authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.admin? } do
>   mount MongodbLogger::Server.new,
>           at: "/mongodb_logger",
>           as: :mongodb_logger,

in my routes.rb. But this didn't help... How can I do such a thing ?

Comment: Ever wonder to do something like [this](https://github.com/resque/resque-web/blob/master/README.md#security)

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks!